# Android 5 - prevent from screen capture

Tags: android, security, capture, android-5.0-lollipop, screen-capture

I have an app that uses some kind of PIN code. So I don't want anyone to record the PIN entering process. 
The newest Android 5 Lollipop provides media.projection API so it's easy to make an app that records device screen (e.g. ilos app).
Is there any way to secure my app so no one could record what I'm touching, entering, etc?

I think it will be a big problem e.g. for bank apps or just for everyone who enters his password.

Please help!

Comment: Have you set [`FLAG_SECURE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE) for the relevant views?

Comment: Ha! FLAG_SECURE helped! Ilos recorded black screen with touch indicators only :)